# How do I add input to a if funtion

Tags: python

How exactly do I add an additional input to this if function, or atleast add a function which will allow me to give the user another option. Thank you, in advance.

```
ask = input  ("Would you like to 1 input an existing number plate \n or 2 view a random number? 1 or 2: ")
if ask == "1":
    print("========================================================================")
    ask = input()("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " )
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking exactly, but one thing I notice in your code: Change this `input()("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " )` to this `input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " )`.

Comment: @MDReza You can add a second line `ask2 = input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this `ask = input()("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " )` is actually in your code, just changing it to `ask = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " )` will fix your problem. You had one extra pair of brackets.

*DISCLAIMER: This works in Python 3.x*

For Python 2, use `raw_input("Your question")` instead of `input("Your question")`.

**As an answer to the question in your own answer:**

> What is wrong in this code?

```
ask = input ("-Would you like to 1 input an existing number plate\n--or 2 view a random number\n1 or 2: ")
if int(ask) == 1:
    print("========================================================================")
while True:
    ask2 = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " ).lower()
if re.ask3("[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}",ask2):
    print("Verification Success")
break

else:
    print("Verification Failed")
```

You have to indent the while loop once (default is 4 spaces) and everything inside of the while loop twice (default 8 spaces). When pasting a code like this, make sure to include all code needed to run. In this case, show your `import re` (I had to find out myself you imported that).

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks, I used this!

Comment: ask = input ("-Would you like to 1 input an existing number plate\n--or 2 view a random number\n1 or 2: ")
if int(ask) == 1:
    print("========================================================================")
while True:
    ask2 = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): " ).lower()
if re.ask3("[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}",ask2):
    print("Verification Success")
break

else:
    print("Verification Failed")                     

How can I fix this invalid synthetix?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an int(1) to str("1").
It should be

```
 if int(ask) == 1:
      # rest of your code
```

or you can use raw_input() function which returns a string value

Comment: You should specify that your solution only holds true for Python 2. For Python 3 input will be a string.

Comment: He might be using Python 3.x, where input() always gives a string.

Comment: This worked, thank you.